# Showing transmission resonance explicit in double delta function potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have managed to show that the transmission coefficient for the double-$\delta$ function is periodically larger than the transmission coefficient for the single-$\delta$ potential. However, I am unsure as to why this effect occurs.

Multiple sources (such as [here](http://przyrbwn.icm.edu.pl/APP/PDF/116/a116z615.pdf) or [here](https://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxpsmAhO3SAhXFiiwKHW78DMs4ChAWCE8wBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.752.5019%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNHRMxzCNl-1g_SjXGE7U1C_WA7Bcw&sig2=WU_9Qxg4QDf87oe3gDjXXw&bvm=bv.150475504,d.bGg)) cite that this phenomena is due to the phase difference between the wave reflected at the second barrier and the wave transmitted through the barriere (that resonance occurs whenever these are equal, due to constructive interference).

Could anyone help me show this more explicitly? In particular, if we have a solution of the form
$$Ae^{ikx} + Be^{-ikx} \, .$$
In between the potentials (located at $a$ and $-a$), how would one show that the transmission coefficient is maximal when the phase difference is equal at the end points of the well?

Comment: In Bohm's book Quantum Theory, Part III, Chapter 11 and 12, is a very extensive treatment of this problem. The necessary condition is that the potential energy is changing at certain speed, and then, as I understand it, this magic enhanced penetration can occur.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Schematic representation of reflected and transmitted waves]
Suppose you evaluated the transmission and reflection amplitudes for a single delta potential.These will be a couple of complex numbers $\tau$ and $\rho$. Now, looking at the picture for a given amplitude $I$ of the wave incoming from the left you will have the relations
$$
A = \rho B e^{2 i k a} + \tau I e^{i k a} 
$$
and
$$
B = \rho A e^{2 i k a}
$$
and finally
$$
O = \tau A e^{i k a}
$$
Solving we find 
$$
O = \frac{\tau^2 e^{2 i k a}}{1-\rho^2 e^{4 i k a}} I
$$
The transmission coefficient is the squared modulus of the factor on the right, which is maximum when 
$$
\arg \left(\rho^2 e^{4 i k a} \right)=2 n \pi 
$$ 
But this is just the phase gain of a plane wave which start from $A$ and come back to it after two reflections.